# Google OnHub and Comcast: traffic from one source computer getting dropped by my ISP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

I have one computer on my network running Windows 10 that periodically loses connectivity to the internet, about a dozen times today.

When this happens, I can still connect to my wireless router and to everything else on the intranet. All of my other local devices can still connect to both the router and the internet.

If I disable and re-enable the adapter in Windows (a Broadcom Wi-Fi adapter) the problem immediately goes away.

Here's a trace to 8.8.8.8 with the problem occurring:

```
tracert 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms    <1 ms     2 ms  onhub.here [192.168.86.1]
  2    25 ms    20 ms    13 ms  96.120.4.173
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    13 ms    16 ms    22 ms  hu-0-4-0-0-cr02.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.93.125]
  6    12 ms    24 ms    22 ms  68.86.86.110
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
...
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

And a working trace after I bounce the adapter:

```
tracert 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    51 ms    13 ms    14 ms  onhub.here [192.168.86.1]
  2    28 ms    53 ms    24 ms  96.120.4.173
  3    26 ms    12 ms    16 ms  68.85.32.213
  4    12 ms    15 ms    11 ms  xe-4-0-12-0-ar01.b0atlanta.ga.atlanta.comcast.net [68.85.111.137]
  5    18 ms    13 ms    13 ms  hu-0-4-0-0-cr02.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.93.125]
  6    29 ms    22 ms    21 ms  68.86.86.110
  7    12 ms    14 ms    14 ms  as174.ashburn.va.ibone.comcast.net [66.208.229.138]
  8    22 ms    15 ms    24 ms  216.239.51.47
  9    13 ms    16 ms    11 ms  216.239.51.245
 10   488 ms    28 ms   338 ms  209.85.243.254
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12    14 ms    12 ms    21 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

Trace complete.
```

The working trace is similar to what I get from other sources on the network.

It seems like the problem is either Windows, the wireless adapter, or Comcast, but I'm not sure how to isolate one.

My failing trace makes it 6 hops out to a Comcast IP before dying. Is it possible that they're mangling traffic just from one source MAC on my network? The problem computer does much higher traffic volume than anything else on my network, though there doesn't seem to be a direct correlation between traffic volume and the outages. I might bounce the adapter and then have it drop again five minutes later with no interesting network traffic happening in between.

Then there's the fact that disabling and re-enabling the adapter consistently fixes it. If Comcast were the problem, I'm not sure why this would work.

I'm using a Google OnHub currently, but experienced the same issue with my previous wireless router.

What can I do to isolate the source of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As your computer is behind a router, you can pretty much rule out problems with your ISP, as the router will be rewriting the packets to come from it.  MAC addresses to not traverse from your LAN onto the wider Internet, so an ISP can't be blocking 1 computer on your lan based on its MAC address.

"Bouncing the adapter" fixing the problem also indicates its something local to your computer - it could be either Windows or the driver, but the problem is way,way,way more likely to be the driver.

(It could be your WIFI router as well, but this is again less likely because you have tried other routers).

One thing to do to confirm it is a problem with your WIFI setup is to plug in an ethernet cable instead and see that the problem does, indeed, go away.

Comment: I'd add to this by saying that for my own instance of this problem, it's almost definitely a problem with the wireless driver.